# is this $_POST considered empty

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to code a error callback using php and ajax.

What I cannot get past is, I am assinging a variable to a `$_POST` in PHP to check for an empty value. If empty, then trigger error message.

However, jquery is passing the post to php as `carton%5B0%5D:carton%5B1%5D:`.

Would php see this as an empty post? What are these numbers etc after carton? carton is actually an array. thanks

+++UPDATE+++

Why is the error triggered when the statement becomes, !empty rather than empty?. 
This is the code that jquery uses to create an input from a slider change event.

```
for(var i = 0;i < $(this).val();i++) {
        $("#carton").append('<div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="carton" class="ui-input-text">Enter box ' + (i + 1) + ' number:</label><input type="text" name="carton['+i+']" id="carton['+i+']" class="carton ui-input-text ui-body-null ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-body-c" /></div>')
      }
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)`  What's in it?

Comment: `%5B1%5D` is url encoded `[1]`

Comment: `%5B` is a `[` and `%5D` is a `]`

Comment: What about doing `echo empty($_POST)`?

Comment: @charles chrome shows output of var_dump as ""

Comment: @Jon i tried that and there were no results in the chrome output even though the fields were posted empty

Comment: @charles the output of the var_dump is in this format:  array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to know whetever $_POST is empty always use var_dump function like this

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

And it might be posted as array, am not quite sure but i think arrays in ajax are like this:

```
array [
[0] => 'item',
[1] => 'item 2'
]
```

array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" }

array(number) means the number of items in the array, {[0],[1]} means the array items IDs means you can use them like $_POST[1] and $_POST[0], => string(0) ; string is the datatype contained in this array item, (0) is the number of characters in that item.

to check whether the POST data is empty or not, you should use empty() function.

finally, use this to post the content you want via jquery, make sure you modify it with what you need

```
$.post("test.php", { carton: "this is the content"} );
```

also you can add more POST fields by adding

```
, newfield: "this is the new field's content"
```

Comment: safad. Doing a var_dump on the post, it produces this:   array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
}

Comment: this means you are posting two 'nameless' variables, and they are both empty, i'll update my answer to explain how var_dump output is readable shortly

Comment: safad, I am using to check for empty condition:  elseif(empty($carton)) {

    //set the response
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';
    $response_array['message'] = 'You must enter a carton for retrieveal';

//if no errors
}  Why is this not triggering error when values are empty? that was the point of my post was would the characters I posted be posted with the posted data to php? Thanks

Comment: let me guess $carton = $_POST['carton']; ??

Comment: then your post name should be carton from the client side, $.post("test.php", { carton: "this is the content"} );

Comment: safad, sorry I am not following you. Please see the update in my original post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending POST data, then no, `$_POST` will not be empty.

Comment: @bollo, check for what values?

Comment: Am I correct in saying that isset represents a $_POST that contains data and !isset $_POST contains no data? In your answer you stated:  $_POST will not be empty  So how do I check for these encoded characters. thanks

Comment: It can be empty if you post data without a key value. Sending a raw string that can't be parsed as a key=value pair will cause PHP to skip adding it to the _POST array - adding data to a PHP array requires a valid key.

Comment: @marc, did you check my comment to safad re var_dump values?